# Rust - как повторить реализацию из PHP?

Tags: rust

Есть реализованный на PHP разбор бинарного файла в hex (читаются данные из файла):

```php
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $bin = fread ($handle , 7 );
    $hex = bin2hex($bin);
}
```

Как это можно повторить-реализовать на Rust?

[`fread`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)  - читает побайтово
[`bin2hex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) - преобразует бинарные в шестнадцатеричное значение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Result};

fn read_as_php(handle: &mut impl Read) -> Result<()> {
    const READ_MAX_LEN: usize = 7;
    let mut bin = [0; READ_MAX_LEN];

    loop {
        let bytes_read = handle.take(READ_MAX_LEN as u64)
                               .read(&mut bin)?;

        if bytes_read == 0 { break; } // EOF

        let hex = bin[..bytes_read].iter()
                        .map(|byte|format!("{byte:02x?}"))
                        .collect::<String>();

        println!("{hex}");
    }

    Ok(())
}

#[test]
fn test_with_file() {
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open("path/to/file")
                                     .expect("Unable to open file");
    let result = read_as_php(&mut file);
    assert!(result.is_ok())
}
```

Output:

```
...
f9ca64adf9ca64
adf9ca64a48159
64a1f9ca641285
cb65aff9ca6412
85cf65baf9ca64
1285ce65a4f9ca
641285c965aef9
...
00000000000000
00000000
```

Comment: Класс. Прикольное решение спасибо!

Comment: А можно уточнить что именно вот здесь происходит ? 

let hex = bin[..bytes_read].iter()
                        .map(|byte|format!("{byte:02x?}"))
                        .collect::<String>();

Comment: Каждый считанный байт (`bin[..bytes_read].iter()`) преобразуем в строку (`.map(|byte|format!("{byte:02x?}"))`), а потом их слепливаем вместе (` .collect::<String>()`).

Comment: А если обратно нам нужно потом в исходном виде записать в файл, нужно: строку разбить по символам, потом как-то побайтово записать в файл?

Comment: Почти) Можно отталкиваться от того, что каждый байт - это два шеснадцатиричных числа. Или взять [специально обученный крейт](https://docs.rs/hex/latest/hex/fn.decode.html).

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!